# How to set bash files globally executable in git by default?

Tags: bash, git, default, chmod

In git when i commit bash files i want those files to be executable like this command do

```
git update-index --chmod=+x <file>
```

But i want it to be set globally by default.

Is there anyway of doing that by default ?

Comment: No, and you don't really want that to be the default either.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any way of doing that.  On Unix systems, Git honors the executable bit of the files that are in the repository.  So on such a system, by the fact that you've set them executable in the working tree, they'll automatically be tracked as executable in Git.

If you're on Windows, there is no executable bit, so you have to update them by hand.  You can try using Windows Subsystem for Linux, which has an executable bit, so you can check out the repository there and work with it.

This feature doesn't exist as a default because (a) it would be hard to implement since it would require intuiting which files are shell scripts (which is nontrivial) and (b) there are many shell scripts which wouldn't be safe to run by themselves.  If you know that this is appropriate for your project, you can write a shell script to set all of your shell scripts executable by default.